# Excel vs Notepad : Number separator

Tags: excel, csv, separator, notepad

I have a problem related to the formatting of the number in CSV files and it depends on the program I use to open it.

If I open the file with notepad I see the following number : 74.4913

However when I open the file with Excel I see the following : 744.913

I have tried changing the decimal separator in Excel options but I was not able to fix anything.

Comment: What is the correct value?

Comment: "I have tried changing the decimal separator in Excel options": Have you changed the thousands separator also? Decimal separator and thousands separator must not be the same.

Comment: The right value is  74.4913 (notepad)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, your Excel's setting is causing this issue.

1. Go to **Options->Advanced**

[image]

2. Make sure the **Automatically insert a decimal point** option is unchecked.

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for your question but unfortunately I had this option disabled